# Find Average in python(json)

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I have a JSON like below:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "subject": "Subject_1",
      "qapali_correct_count": "12"
    },
    {
      "subject": "Subject_2",
      "qapali_correct_count": "9"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "subject": "Subject_1",
      "qapali_correct_count": "14"
    },
    {
      "subject": "Subject_2",
      "qapali_correct_count": "15"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "subject": "Subject_1",
      "qapali_correct_count": "11"
    },
    {
      "subject": "Subject_2",
      "qapali_correct_count": "12"
    }
  ]
]
```

I have to output every subject's average: for example: **subject_1 = 12.33, subject_2=12**
I tried this code it works but I just wonder is there any option to speed up this code, Are there any other efficient ways to achieve it.

```
results = Result.objects.filter(exam=obj_exam, grade=obj_grade)
student_count = results.count()
final_data = {}
for result in results:
    st_naswer_js = json.loads(result.student_answer_data_finish)
    for rslt in st_naswer_js:
        previus_data = final_data.get(rslt['subject'],0)
        previus_data = previus_data+int(rslt['qapali_correct_count'])
        final_data.update({rslt['subject']:previus_data})

for dudu, data in final_data.items():
    tmp_data = data/student_count
    final_data[dudu]=tmp_data
print(final_data)
```

Please note that it is a Django project.

Comment: "Please note that it is a Django project." Do you expect that to matter to the code for this specific problem? Why?

Comment: Is the `student_answer_data_finish` a `CharField`? You can use a `JsonField` to prevent serializing and deserializing.

Comment: yes it is a CharField, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question has several non-relevant bits. I'll stick to this part:

> I have to output every subject's average: for example: **subject_1 = 12.33, subject_2=12**

I'll assume the list of results above is in a list called `results`. If it's json-loaded per student, handling that is probably already in your existing code. Primary focus below is on `subject_score`.

Store the score of each subject in a dictionary, whose values are lists of scores. I'm using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here, with `list` as the default factory so when a dictionary value which doesn't exist is accessed, it gets initialised to an empty list (rather than throwing an KeyError which would happen with a standard dictionary.

```py
import collections

subject_score = collections.defaultdict(list)

for result in results:
    for stud_score in result:
        # add each score to the list of scores for that subject
        # use int or float above as needed
        subject_score[stud_score['subject']].append(int(stud_score['qapali_correct_count']))

# `subject_score` is now:
# defaultdict(list, {'Subject_1': [12, 14, 11], 'Subject_2': [9, 15, 12]})

averages = {sub: sum(scores)/len(scores) for sub, scores in subject_score.items()}
```

`averages` is:

```py
{'Subject_1': 12.333333333333334, 'Subject_2': 12.0}
```

Or you can print or save to file, db, etc. as needed.